# why i can't run binary from /home path

Tags: shell-script

I have a binary "test", I try to run it as follows:

```
root@g-6:~# ./home/test
-bash: ./home/test: No such file or directory
```

Have you an idea, please, about the error ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: or /home/test without the . in front.

Comment: Off topic, but is `test` a program from a trusted source? If not, or if you wrote and compiled it yourself, it might be a better idea to run it as a normal user rather than as root.

Comment: The error is entirely self-explanatory. What could possibly be unclear about it? It's saying that `./home/text` does not refer to any file or directory that exists. Were you really in a directory with a sub-directory called `home` containing a filed called `test`? That seems really unlikely. What do commands like `ls ./home/test` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the program really located in `/home/test`? With ordinary Linux distributions, that would be an odd place to put a program.
Assuming that you mean your home directory, the usual location would be `/home/` plus your user name, so the program would be at `/home/researcher/test`. Or if it's in the home directory for root, `/root/test` (note: no "home" there).

So that's what you would type if you want to run it. `/home/researcher/test` as a normal user, `/root/test` as root.

Or go to the directory first with `cd /home/researcher` (or `cd /root`) and then type `./test`.

The thing with `.` is that it means "the current directory". So if you're in `~`, which you are, the command `./home/test` would mean `~/home/test`, which is not the same as `/home/test`!